# Which 16 antenna locations were used this MeerKAT radio image?

Tags: radio-astronomy, radio-telescope

The final configuration of the [MeerKAT radio array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeerKAT) will be 64 dishes. In the [press release of July 16, 2016](http://www.ska.ac.za/releases/20160716.php) a radio image is shown using a completed sub-set of 16 dishes.

Which 16 are these? I can find documents on-line with coordinates for 64 location, (sometimes numbered 1 through 64, [but not here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.2935.pdf)), but I can't figure out which 16 are used to produce this image.

I found images of KAT-7 and MeerKAT in google maps - maybe someday we can get daily ground truth updates from [Planet Labs](https://www.planet.com/), but for right now I'll stick to stackexchange.

Image [from the press release](http://www.ska.ac.za/releases/20160716.php):

[image]

[image]

**Above:** MeerKAT *array core* from Google Maps at (30.7136109S, 21.4399576E). The remaining sites are farther away and can be seen if one zooms out.

[image]

**Above:** KAT-7 array from Google Maps at (30.7217011S, 21.4070518E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lorenzo Raynard, spokesperson for SKA Africa was gracious enough to send me the map with the sixteen sites below, and I've duplicated the dots on a larger format map.

It's been quite a while, probably the array has grown since this "first-light" image.

Next step (strictly for fun) will be to try to make a [UV map](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26413/7982) for this configuration.

[image]

[image]