# Generate East and North unit vectors tangent to a point on the celestial sphere, using vectors?

Tags: mathematics

I am stuck and a little embarrassed.

I'm trying to implement [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/26467/7982). I have a unit vector $w$ pointing in the direction of a radio source on the celestial sphere.

$u$ and $v$ are the two other, mutually orthogonal unit vectors that point *east* and *north* from that point, tangent to the sphere.

Without back-converting to R.A. and Dec or using trigonometry, is there a simple way to generate $u$ and $v$ vectorially?

Slide 38 [here](https://www.strw.leidenuniv.nl/radioastronomy/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=radio_astronomy_lec_4_ma_garrett.pdf) may or may not be helpful, I think my description is sufficient by itself.

Comment: How did you determine **w**?

Comment: @MikeG In my question, $w$ *is a given*. It can come from any source. If it comes from orbital mechanics, it's the normalized relative position vector $\mathbf{r}/|r|$, or it can come from an initial RA/Dec value that's been spun around the Earth's axis for 24 hours [like I did here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30311/7982) when I built `SgrA_star` (which is what would be $w$), or it can be from somewhere else entirely. From any given $w$ I'm asking how to get $u$ and $v$ *without going back to trigonometry*. Can it be done using just vectors somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ points to the north celestial pole, then the eastward tangent vector is

$$\mathbf{\hat{u} = \frac{\hat{n} \times \hat{w}}{\|\hat{n} \times \hat{w}\|}}$$

and the northward tangent vector is

$$\mathbf{\hat{v} = \frac{\hat{w} \times \hat{u}}{\|\hat{w} \times \hat{u}\|}}$$

$\mathbf{\|\hat{w} \times \hat{u}\|}$ analytically should be 1 but can be slightly different numerically.

Comment: Bingo! renormalize, facepalm, repeat...