# In astronomical interferometry, what values do the points in the uv-plane have?

Tags: radio-astronomy, mathematics, interferometry

As I understand it, the image of an interferometer is the inverse fourier transform of the information in the uv plane. For each baseline (vector between any two telescopes in the array), representing a certain wavelength along its orientation, there is a point in the uv plane.

[image]

(image from [lecture notes from nrado.edu](https://science.nrao.edu/facilities/alma/naasc-workshops/nrao-cd-spf1/BasicsInterf.pdf))

But what value does each of these data points have? I'd expect them to contain amplitude and phase information, but which exactly?

How do I get these values from the signals of my telescopes? Say, I already computed the phase shifts between the signals, what values do I put in the uv plane?

Comment: different but related question: [Math behind a uv plot in interferometry?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26413)

Comment: @TheBigJoe1489 This is just a note to save [your link](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1989ASPC....6...11T/0000011.000.html) in case your link-only-answer gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggeling to understand 2080's question, so I looked up the given reference which might be worth re-quoting:

[image]

With this additional information in hand, the question (initially) seemed to be mainly about the  interpretation of 2D [discrete Fourier trafo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), using the terms of astronomy.

If that interpretation was correct, I suggest e.g. http://bigwww.epfl.ch/demo/ip/demos/FFT/ which offers an intutive and interactive approach to Fourier transformation in general.

**Edit:** The question has been edited, and the main issue seems to be *How do I get these values $V(u,v)$ from the signals $T(x,y)$ of my telescopes?* I write "seems" since I am not 100% certain that $T(x,y)$ are indeed the signals of the telescope.

What I know from [Math behind a uv plot in interferometry?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26413/math-behind-a-uv-plot-in-interferometry) is that the units used in the u-v-plane are wavelength, e.g. in meters.

#### References

- Lecture by Jason Hessels on [Radio Astronomy: The Techniques of Radio Interferometry I: Basics](https://www.astron.nl/astrowiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=ra_uva:ra_uva_lecture6.pdf) overs an introduction I found quite accessible.

Comment: I know how to apply a fourier transform, but I do not know where the amplitude/phase information in each of the uv-dots comes from/how it is computed

Comment: @2080 I am still not fully understanding mathematically your issue, so let's try to break it down: (a) You have the functional form or the values of $T(x,y)$ given in real space, correct? (b) In the $uv$-plane, you have $V(u,v)$ fully determined by Fourier transformation. So at each point $(u,v)$ on the uv-plane, there is a (single) value $V(u,v)$. Is your question about that?

Comment: See my edited question