# Limits of space telescope?

Tags: telescope, space-telescope

[Watching this video](https://youtu.be/R8KlX2OFg-s) describing the "next generation" space telescope, it seems like the biggest mirror will be ~6 meters in diameter.

Theoretically, if a telescope was built in space instead of shipping it pre-built, and the mirror was, not a few meters, but a few kilometers, (and whatever other important aspects of a space telescope that a novice like myself has no idea about, multiply them by a few orders of magnitude) would it provide benefits proportional to the size difference?

Comment: That is an incredible video, wow! I think it can serve as the basis of many many new questions here. *Thanks for the link!*

Comment: here's another already: [How do HabEx's internal coronagraph and external starshade work together and complement each other? What is it that each can do that the other can't?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40601/7982)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely! The performance of *any* telescope depends on its diameter. A larger instrument not only collects more light, but also provides better resolution than a smaller instrument. The resolution limit is calculated from:

$R_{arcsec}\ = {1.22\ \lambda \over D_{mm}}$

whereas limiting magnitude is calculated from

$L_{mag}\ =\ 2.5\ +\ 5\ log\ D_{mm}$

I *suppose* there are eventual limits to $R_{arcsec}$, but I have never heard of any. As for limiting magnitude, as it’s a logarithmic formula, it grows very slowly as $D_{mm}$ increases, but a larger telescope is still a gain.

The whole thing is to balance $R_{arcsec}$, $L_{mag}$, and $$$, of course!

Comment: not necessarily a limit but might require correction: [Can weak gravitational lensing or microlensing-induced wavefront distortion limit resolution of absurdly large aperture telescopes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29090/7982)